# Dúvidas em relação ao uso da câmera, via Intent

Tags: android, android-camera

Boa tarde pessoal, comecei um estagio há uns dois meses e tanto essa comunidade quanto a Stack estrangeira tem sido meus melhoras amigos nessa nova jornada.

Atualmente eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo pela IDE Android Studio 2.1.2 e me deparei com alguns problemas ao utilizar a API nativa da câmera no projeto. Preciso tirar uma foto com a câmera, salvar essa foto em alguma pasta, cache de preferência, e não disponibilizar essa foto na mídia e nem pra nenhuma outra aplicação, apenas a minha.

Já utilizei a Intent direto da câmera e cada solução que procuro eu travo em algum ponto.

Se escolho um Path para salvar a foto, o data do `onResultActivity` vem como Null.
Se eu salvo sem passar o caminho, ele fica salvo na galeria do celular.  Tento criar uma pasta cache para salvar a foto, mas dá erro na hora de criar o diretório. E se cria o diretório, salva em uma pasta paras as fotos do APP e também mostra na mídia.

Não sei se tenho que utilizar o modo programático pra utilizar a câmera ou se o que eu quero consigo resolver com a Intent nativa da câmera.

EDIT:
Vou colocar o ultimo código que executei para melhor entendimento.

```
private void abrirCamera(){
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
            //        data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            AtualizaCor task = new AtualizaCor();
            task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.com/index.html" });
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

eu comentei essas duas linhas aqui:

```
//fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
//intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
```

porque estavam trazendo o data como Null. E eu preciso dele para deixar uma previa da foto em uma miniatura.

Comment: Se você passar um *path* não necessita do *data*, a foto é gravada no *path*. Sem saber qual é o código que está a usar é difícil saber o que está mal.

Comment: Note que para poder utilizar as linhas que comentou tem de adicionar a permissão **WRITE_EX‌​TERNAL_STORAGE** no *AndroidManifest.xml*: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
`

Comment: já estão adicionadas

Comment: Em uma das pesquisas que fiz eu vi que para utilizar o arquivo salvo apenas no meu APP, tem que salva-los na memoria interna. Assim dessa forma que mantenho controle, sigilo e qdo o APP for deletado, as fotos também serão. Caso ainda tenha na pasta, porque pretendo usar uma pasta Cache.

Comment: A aplicação da câmara não pode gravar na memória interna da sua aplicação, não tem permissões.

Comment: Em algumas pesquisas eu vi que para salvar na memoria interna o APP não precisa de permissões. Como estou abrindo a câmera pelo APP então ele não poderia gravar a imagem na memoria interna?

Comment: Isso é verdade para a sua aplicação. Apesar de ser "chamada" pela sua aplicação a câmara  é outra aplicação.

Comment: Preciso então usar a câmera totalmente programada. Abrir a câmera, abrir tela de visualização, preview e tals? Será que isso resolve?

Comment: Sim mas é um pouco complicado. Se quer que as fotos sejam apagadas ao desinstalar a app e não apareçam "na mídia"  em vez de `File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");` use `File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(), "MyCameraApp");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aplicação da câmara não tem permissão para gravar na *internal storage* da sua aplicação.

Mas pode<sup>(Ver nota)</sup> gravar na *external storage* que é atribuída à sua aplicação.

Arquivos gravados nesta área serão eliminados quando a sua aplicação for desinstalada e não aparecem na Galeria.

O seguinte código permite usar a aplicação da câmara para tirar uma foto e apresentá-la numa *ImageView*.

A imagem é gravada na *primary shared/external storage* do dispositivo, na área reservada à sua aplicação.

O caminho completo depende do dispositivo e será qualquer coisa do género:

> /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/nome.da.sua.package/files/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20160817_000919.jpg

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
    private ImageView img;
    private Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagem);
        abrirCamera();
    }

    private void abrirCamera(){

        // cria um Uri com o caminho do arquivo para guardar a foto
        //ex: /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/nome.da.sua.package/files/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20160817_000919.jpg
        fileUri = getOutputPictureUri("MyCameraApp");

        if(fileUri != null) {

            // Cria o intent para chamar a câmara
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // seta o caminho do arquivo para guardar a foto
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // inicia a captura da foto
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                //Lê a foto gravada, redimensiona para 300x300 e coloca-a
                // na ImageView
                img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(fileUri, 300, 300));

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Captura da foto cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Captura da foto falhou", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();
            }
        }
    }

    // Retorna um Uri com o caminho do arquivo para guardar a foto
    private Uri getOutputPictureUri(String pasta){

        String mm = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED;
        String externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(externalStorageState) ||
           Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(externalStorageState)){
            return null;
        }


        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), pasta);

        // Cria a pasta se não existir
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Toast.makeText(this,pasta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Cria o path completo com o nome da foto
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                                  "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Uri fileUri,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        String path = fileUri.getPath();

        // Primeiro faz o decode com inJustDecodeBounds=true para obter as dimensões
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calcula as novas dimensões
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Faz o decode do bitmap e redimensiona
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // Altura e largura da imagem
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            //Calcula o maior valor de inSampleSize, que é uma potência de 2,
            // que mantém altura e o comprimento maiores do que os valores pedidos.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Notas:

- Se a aplicação for para rodar em dispositivos com API Level inferior à 19 é necessária a seguinte permissão:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  ```
- Se `targetSdkVersion` for 24 ou superior deve ter em conta as alterações às permissões com impacto na partilha de arquivos. Veja como nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187127/2541).
- Se quiser guardar as fotos numa pasta publica(para que a foto não seja eliminada quando a sua app for desinstalada) use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Sua solução resolveu meus problemas. Estou agora estudando esse código e procurando uma maneira de não estourar a memória do smartphone ao mostrar as fotos na activity do app

Comment: Se as redimensionar, passado valores baixos(os necessários) ao método `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile()`, não irá estourar.