# Erro FileUriExposedException no Android N

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permission

Olá amigos estou enfrentando o seguinte erro:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1488344088086.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri().

A intenção é abrir a câmera, bater uma foto e gravar a foto em uma ImageView, funcionava até o Android 6.0, mas agora no Android 7 parou de funcionar, alguém sabe como solucionar ?

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener onOriginSelect() {
    return new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    if (PermissionUtils.checkPermission(PeopleActivity.this, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE, permissoes)) {
                        File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                        String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        file = new File(nomeImagem);
                        intentGlobal = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intentGlobal.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(intentGlobal, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PeopleActivity.this, "ERRO CAM PERM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (PermissionUtils.checkPermission(PeopleActivity.this, GALERIA_REQUEST_CODE, permissoes)) {
                        intentGlobal = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intentGlobal, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PeopleActivity.this, "PERM GALERIA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALERIA_REQUEST_CODE:
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    file = new File(path);
                    break;
                }
                Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(file.getPath()).asBitmap().centerCrop().into(imagePeople);
        }
    }
}
```

Grato !!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O Android N sofreu algumas [alterações de comportamento](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html), entre elas [alterações às permissões](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm) com impacto na [partilha de arquivos](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files).

As aplicações para Android N ficam agora impossibilitadas de expor URIs do tipo `file://` para fora da aplicação, devendo usar um URI do tipo `content://` e conceder a ele uma permissão temporária de acesso.
A forma mais fácil de o fazer é usar um [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

A sua implementação é feita em 3 passos:

1. [Especificar o FileProvider no AndroidManifest](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html#DefineProvider).

   ```
   <application
       ...>
       <provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true"
           android:exported="false">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
       </provider>
       ...
   </application>
   ```
2. [Especificar os directórios partilhados](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html#DefineMetaData) - Crie um arquivo *xml*, na pasta `res/xml/`, com o nome indicado no passo 1 em `android:resource="@xml/filepaths"`. Nele deve ser incluído, por cada directório, um elemento XML do tipo `<paths> </paths>`

   Exemplo:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
   </paths>
   ```
3. [Obter o URI para o arquivo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) - Em vez de `Uri.fromFile()` deverá usar `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` que retorna um URI do tipo `content://`, conforme requerido pelo novo modelo.

   Exemplo:

   ```
   fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
           MainActivity.this,
           "com.example.myapp.fileprovider",
           requestFile);
   ```

**Referências:**

- [Alterações de comportamento do Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html).
- [Setting Up File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html).
- [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).