# Como utilizo o FileProvider e Bitmap juntos?

Tags: java, android, base64, bitmap

Estou tendo problemas para enviar uma foto para o servidor, mais especificamente no trecho: `"bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);"`. Sempre ao tirar a foto ele apresenta erro nessa linha. Anteriormente ao invés do `"FileProvider.getUriForFile"` utilizava `"Uri.fromFile"` e funcionava normalmente, mas esse método não funciona no `Android 7.0` em diante, então tive que mudar para o FileProvider, porem não consigo fazer o código funcionar. Alguém sabe uma solução para esse problema???

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       //Metodo para tirar foto.

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
            startActivityForResult(i, 10);
            getFileUri();
        }
    });


private void getFileUri() {

    image_name = "testing123.jpg";
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            + File.separator + image_name
    );

    String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
    file_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(CarActivity.this, authorities, file);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        new Encode_image().execute();
    }
}

private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        bitmap.recycle();

        byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
        encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Você declarou o FileProvider no AndroidManifest? Se não, veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187127/2541).

Comment: Sim, declarei da seguinte forma:

'<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
        </provider>'

Comment: Tambem criei no xml o filepaths da seguinte forma:

'<paths>
    <external-path path="." name="mediaimages"/>
</paths>'