# Criar pasta no diretório do Android

Tags: android

Eu fiz um APP que faz o monitoramento de eventos, e por fim, gera um relatório em PDF com os dados desse evento. Mas na hora de criar o arquivo, se o dispositivo estiver com Android Nougat, nada é gerado. Já tentei criar uma pasta, salvar o arquivo em pastas que já existem, olhei o Android Developer, e nada funcionou.
Como posso resolver esse problema?

PS: Em outras versões funciona normalmente.

```
try {

        filename = "CCB - Dados Reunião.pdf";

        document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DADOS CCB";
        //path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/CCB";

        File dir = new File(path, filename);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        fOut.flush();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
        document.open();} catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        document.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Sem código ou erro, não é possível dizer com certeza, no entanto o mais provável é ser problema de [permissões em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120859/2541) ou [permissões na partilha de arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187119/2541).

Comment: Muito obrigado, seu comentário me faz lembrar de tentar fazer a permissão em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei esse trecho para o usuário dar a permissão em tempo de execução.

```
    private final int PERMISSAO_REQUEST = 1;
```

No onCreate:

```
//USUARIA DAR A PERMISSAO PARA LER
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSAO_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    //USUARIA DAR A PERMISSAO PARA ESCREVER
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSAO_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```