# Abrir um arquivo passado via intent no Android 7

Tags: android, android-intent

O programa funciona nas versões anteriores do Android, somente na Nougat que não.

Recebo o arquivo de algum programa, por exemplo o gerenciador de arquivos:

```
Uri arqUri = intent.getData();
```

E obtenho o caminho para esse arquivo:

```
String caminho = arqUri.getPath();
```

O retorno no caso dos meus testes é : **/file/sdcard/Download/ss.rlc**
Mas não consigo abrir esse arquivo no Android 7, ocorre erro de que não existe. Nas outras versões do Android consigo ler o arquivo normalmente.

Se utilizo esse caminho (digitado manualmente):**/storage/emulated/0/Download/ss.rlc** eu consigo ler normalmente esse arquivo.

O arquivo poderá ser enviado por qualquer programa como telegram, email ou outros, então o problema é conseguir obter um caminho que seja possível abrir o arquivo no Nougat mantendo a compatibilidade com as versões anteriores. O nome do arquivo poderá ser qualquer um e o caminho também, por siso não posso ter nada fixo no código.

Aqui a parte do código onde tento ler o arquivo:

```
        Uri arqUri = intent.getData();
    if (arqUri != null) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis;
            String caminho = arqUri.getPath();
            Log.d("Artur", "caminho : "+caminho);
            //File fx = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ss.rlc"); //FUNCIONA
            File fx = new File(caminho);
            fis = new FileInputStream(fx);

            fis.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Artur", "Erro: "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Julgo que o problema tem haver com as alterações nas permissões na partilha de arquivos, como explicado nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187127/2541).

Comment: Interessante e obrigado. Mas acredito que isso resultaria em outro problema. Nas descrição tenho que listar os diretórios de que preciso ter acesso. E eu não sei quais são. Só saberei na hora de usar pois não sei que aplicação está sendo usada para enviar o arquivo. POde ser Telegram, Wats ou outro de bate papo. Pode ser qualquer programa de email. Ou qualquer forma de compartilhamento de arquivos. Como postei abaixo eu tenho o direito de acesso, apenas o inicio do caminho que deve ser alterado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui um contorno nada bonito mas funcionou para o Telegram e o gerenciador de arquivos:

```
caminho = caminho.replace("/media","/storage/emulated/0");
caminho = caminho.replace("/file/sdcard","/storage/emulated/0");
```

Mas ainda busco uma solução mais correta.