# quero setar a foto na imageview

Tags: android

sou novo em programação e estou tendo dificuldade em setar a foto na `imageview`, sendo que já tira foto e salva na galeria, mas não está setando.

```
public void usarCamera() {

        File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imagem = new File(diretorio.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        uri  = Uri.fromFile(imagem);

        Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CAMERA);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

               if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALERIA_IMAGENS){
                Intent novaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
                sendBroadcast(novaIntent);
                caminhoDaImagem = uri.getPath();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dá algum erro ? Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147490/2541)

Answer (score -1):

Tenta usar o Picasso pra isso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Ficaria algo como:

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(caminhoDaImagem)
    .into(imageview)
```